# How to get variable names inside a function in julia

Tags: function, julia

For example

```
function f(x)
    # do something
    # then I assigned the outside variable name of 'x' to y
    println(y)
end

f(1)
```

I will get

```
# something and
1
```

then,

```
a = 1
f(a)
```

I will get

```
# something and
"a"
```

Is it possible in julia? If not, how can I get my function operation log?

Comment: This is possible with macros.

Comment: Can you log the function from the calling function, instead of within the function? This way, the information will be readily available (sometimes, and quite often, the answer to a question, is changing the question)

Comment: @DanGetz I have to, my final function will modify a sophisticated struct object and log the operation in the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most idiomatic way would be to slightly change your interface of `f` and require a keyword argument:

```
julia> function f(;kwargs...)
           for (k, v) in kwargs
               println("$k = $v")
           end
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(a = 1)
a = 1
```

Alternatively (short of inspecting stack traces), you need something macro-based:

```
julia> struct Quot
           expr
           value
         end

julia> macro quot(e)
           return :($Quot($(QuoteNode(e)), $e))
       end
@quot (macro with 1 method)

julia> function f2(x::Quot)
           println(x)
       end
f2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> x = 2
2

julia> f2(@quot x)
Quot(:x, 2)
```

Comment: I tried your second way to solve my problem. It is very good. Thx!

Comment: That's fine, but there are definitely more idiomatic ways.

Comment: Yes. I found the users don't like to add a macro before the arguments in the function. They ask a normal way to use the function and the function can get the variable name inside the function silently.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need a simples macro that dumps function calls that still get executed could be:

```
macro logs(expr)
    @info expr
    expr
end
```

And this can be used as:

```
julia> a = π/2;

julia> @logs sin(a)
[ Info: sin(a)
1.0
```